# android background image problem

Tags: android, mobile, android-layout, android-image

I am trying to set an image as background. I edit the xml layout file. But when i put the image on the drawable folder, it gives an error on the project name. What is the problem? Is it related to size of image? How much is the biggest size for image that android can run?

Comment: Show us what the error is. Where are u putting the image? Is it into the res folder?

Comment: In addition to Francesco's comments, could you show us the XML layout file you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Probably your image name is incorrect , resource items cant have numbers , special characters ( _ is fine ) & upper case characters.

Answer (score 0):

Image Size never give Errors, Format of the size will give the error.. Check the valid format..

If you upload the bigsize image , it display only small portion from Display.getWidth to Display.GetHeight position.